# New project output not shown in android emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-emulator

I had created an old android project called LinearLayouts and written some code in activity_main.xml under the layout folder. The code ran perfectly fine on the emulator. But now I have edited activity_main.xml and changed the code. The problem is that edited or changed code is not shown on the emulator. Could anybody help me to find solution to this problem. Below is the old code and new code in activity_main.xml. When I run the new code even then the emulator shows the old code output. The new code or edited code output is not shown instead of that it shows the old code output itself.

**My previous code of activity_main.xml is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/label"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Type Here:" 
     />

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edittext1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/label"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:ems="10" >
   <requestFocus />
</EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My new or edited code in activity_main.xml is:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     </LinearLayout>
  </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Click on the Project then clean your project and test again

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the files from your /bin folder (except for AndroidManifest.xml) in your project root and try again.